# Отправка id через form метод POST

Tags: php

Мне нужно отправить на страницу id, я дошел к такому решению:

```
<? $post['id'] = 1; ?>
```

`<form method="POST" action="./post.php">
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" 
     name="<?echo $post['id'];?>" value="Прочесть польностью"/>
</form>`

Потом достаю id таким способом:

`$id_post = array_keys($_POST)[0];`

получаю такой массив

`Array
(
    [1] => Прочесть польностью
)`

В массиве мое значение `$post['id']` как ключ а надпись кнопки как значение.

Как можно получить масив `$_POST` такого формата?

`Array
(
    [id] => 1
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ, может кому пригодиться

```
<form method="POST" action="./post.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value = "<?echo $post['id'];?>">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" name="<?echo $post['id'];?>" value="Читати повністью"/>
            </form>
```

`Array
(
    [1] => Читати повністью
    [id] => 1
)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="./post.php">
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" 
 name="<?PHP echo $post['id'];?>" value="Прочитать польностью"/>`</form>`
```

Тег PHP забыли

Comment: Тут такая штука что мне не обязательно php прописывать. Код рабочий, получаеться я $post['id'] отправляю, потом он в массиве $_POST как ключ